# How to pass access token value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bearer-token

I have this codes to get access token which should pass from signin screen -> navscreen -> homescreen-> griddashboard->forms ->add new post and send the post request to server with the token

Here is how I get the token

```
 Future<dynamic> handleGetTokenSilently() async {
    String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID";
    final  result = await msal.acquireTokenSilent([SCOPE], authority);
    if(result !=null){
      print('access token (truncated): ${result.accessToken}');
      return result; //passing the result
    }
    else{
      print('no access token');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and then passing it to the Navscreen

```
refreshSignedInStatus() async {
    bool loggedIn = await msal.getSignedIn();
    if (loggedIn) {
      isSignedIn = loggedIn;
      if(isSignedIn) {
        dynamic data = await handleGetAccount();
        dynamic token = await handleGetTokenSilently();
        dynamic currentAccount = data;
        dynamic result = token; <--- getting the token
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NavScreen(
              currentAccount : currentAccount, // <--- Passing required named parameter "currentAccount" in NavScreen widget.
              result: result, <-- Passing required named parameter "result" in NavScreen widget
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      // Remaining code for navigation
    }
  }
```

then pass it to home screen

```
class NavScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavScreen({Key key, @required this.currentAccount, @required this.result}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavScreenState createState() => _NavScreenState();
  final dynamic currentAccount;
  final dynamic result;
}

class _NavScreenState extends State<NavScreen> {
  final List<Widget> _screens = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _screens.add(Home(currentAccount: widget.currentAccount));
    _screens.add(Home(result: widget.result));
```

then on the homescreen I have a gridview that has options to go to different pages.

how the gridview is called

```
 SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        GridDashboard()
      ],
```

and then on the Griddashboard

```
     class _GridDashboardState extends State<GridDashboard> {
  Items home = new Items(screen: Home());

  Items update = new Items(screen: CameraExampleHome());

  Items bluetooth = new Items(screen: BluetoothApp());

  Items forms = new Items(screen: FormsDashboard());

  Items supervisor = new Items(screen: Home());

  Items messages = new Items(screen: Home());

  Items settings = new Items(screen: Settings());

  Items check = new Items(screen: Home());

  Items logout = new Items(screen: AudioRecorder());
```

how can I pass the token from the homescreen to the Griddashboard to FormsDashboard() and to post values to the server with the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to define global variables if u want that in entire app but it will get lost once the user close the app.

the best way is to store that token value in database like shared_preferences or 'hive` . Here is the doc of https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences and https://pub.dev/packages/hive resp

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('token', tokenvalue);
```

for getting bool value

```
bool counter = prefs.getString('token');
```