# Passing Variable Token Key value in a Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an api_service.dart file and when the user logs in I save the `json.decode(response.body)['key']` in a variable as Tkey. I want to be able to access it in the same file but in a different function when I am trying to access user details:

I am not sure how to apply this answer [How to pass access token value in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911301/how-to-pass-access-token-value-in-flutter) to my code

```
class APIService {
  static var client = http.Client();
  static Future<bool> login(
    LoginRequestModel model,
  ) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', };
    var url = Uri.parse(
      Config.apiURL + Config.loginAPI,    );

    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await SharedService.setLoginDetails(
        loginResponseJson(
          response.body,        ),      );
      print("No.2 Test ${response.body}"); <-------{"key":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
      var Tkey = json.decode(response.body)['key'];
      print("No.2 Test $Tkey"); <-------------- xxxxxxxxxxxxx
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;    }  }

  static Future<User> fetchUser() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userProfileAPI);
    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Token $Tkey', <--------------- I want to print here the value of the key
      }, );

    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User');
    }  }}
```

My question how can I get access to the key to be used in the `fetchUser()` ?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to set and get token value. It will be also helpful to navigated the user if its login to directly to homeScreen on app relaunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable in the global scope or in a separate file, then when this method is executing, assign that key to it, then use it everywhere else in your app.

in a separate file:

```
String GlobalTkey = "";
```

now in your method replace the following:

```
   print("No.2 Test ${response.body}"); <-------{"key":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
  var Tkey = json.decode(response.body)['key'];
  print("No.2 Test $Tkey"); <-------------- xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

with  this:

```
   print("No.2 Test ${response.body}"); <-------{"key":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
  var Tkey = json.decode(response.body)['key'];
  GlobalTkey = Tkey; // you need to import the file where the variable exists
  print("No.2 Test $Tkey"); <-------------- xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

now everywhere in your app including different files, methods, widgets, classes... you can use `GlobalTkey`